# How to disable image fade in effect in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Situation**

- Dynamically toggling images
- React Native
- Dev mode
- Android

**Problem**

- The images fade in when appearing during dev mode. This is an issue since I am developing and tuning images animations with actual fade in effects. Is it possible to disable the fade in effect?

**Attempts**

- Switched to release mode. Works but not appropriate during development.
- Minimizing the image file size. No visible difference.
- Minimizing the image display size. No visible difference.

Comment: Can you post some code you are using

Comment: Are you using Animated.spring() anywhere in the page? I had an issue where using this in one component in the visual tree meant that every element on the page would get a fade-in animation. Drove me a little bit crazy before I worked out where it was coming from.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I went with designing the fade in part of the animation in release mode for a while, not very convenient but it worked.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just set `fadeDuration={0}` to `Image` component, this is not documented

You can check [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10194) for more information

Comment: I was using [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) just to get rid of this fain-in effect! Now I know the fade effect is by intention and I can get rid of it by using `fadeDuration={0}`! +1

Comment: Just pointing out this is now [documented](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#fadeduration).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to prevent the fade animation by wrapping my `<Image />` with a custom `ViewGroupManager` and setting `ReactImageView.mFadeDuration` to zero with reflection before the Image is added to the custom `ViewGroup`.
**Edit:** <del>But this adds a noticeable delay when displaying the image :(</del> There's actually no delay.

Something like this:

```java
public class NoFadeImageWrapper extends ViewGroup {
    public NoFadeImageWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        if (child instanceof ReactImageView) {
            ((ReactImageView) child).setFadeDuration(0);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(child, "mIsDirty", true);
        }
        super.onViewAdded(child);
    }
}
```

`ReflectionUtils.setField` implementation:

```java
public class ReflectionUtils {
    public static void setField(Object obj, String name, Object value) {
        try {
            Field field = getField(obj.getClass(), name);
            if (field == null) {
                return;
            }
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(obj, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```